# Extracting loops in llvm bitcode from functions/modules

Tags: loops, llvm, bitcode

Is it possible to **extract from llvm bitcode the loop(s) inside a function or module?**
I'm migrating an LLVM `LoopPass` to an independent bitcode reader/writer application. The major reason for the migration is the hardship of debugging opt passes, but there are other reasons too. I've searched the API of Function/Module/BasicBlock, but couldn't find anything close.
**Since the LoopPass does this exactly, I'm pretty sure it's possible right?** I mean something like this:

```
Function f;
for (auto loop = f.getLoops().begin(); loop != f.getLoops().end(); loop++)
{
    // process loop here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [LoopInfo](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html) and you create it via a dominator tree:

```
DominatorTree dt(function);
LoopInfo li(dt);
for(Instruction * foo : bar) {
  Loop * l = li.getLoopFor(foo->getParent());
```